# How to insert a reference to a figure in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I'd like to insert a reference to a figure, but I don't find how to do it. For example, I would like to insert something like: "The figure 1 shows a bear eating a salmon.".

By clicking on "Insert Cross-reference" I can choose:

- Reference type: Figure
- Insert reference to: Only label and number

This will insert `Figure 1` instead of `figure 1`.

Is it possible to just insert the number, not the label and the number?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have added the figure, configure the caption for it:

- Right-click on the figure and select `Insert Caption...`
- Set the Label and Position as you like them, but be sure to check `Exclude label from caption`

Then, add the cross reference:

- Click Insert on the Ribbon, then click Cross Reference in the Links group
- Set `Reference type:` to Figure
- Set `Insert reference to:` to Entire caption
- In `For which caption:`, select the appropriate number

This should insert just the number wherever you are typing the cross reference text.

NB:  Your example text: "The figure 1 shows a bear eating a salmon." would normally be just "Figure 1 shows a bear eating a salmon." which is probably why the type is included by default.